# The grammar of the parenthesis clause

Tags: grammar

Among the following sentences, which is right?

> - John, when work alone, is very productive.
> - John, when working alone, is very productive.

And also, what is this kind of clause called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one doesn't seem to be correct to me, unless you write it as:

> John, when **he works** alone, is very productive.
>
> John, when working alone, is very productive.

The second is correct.

I'd say they are both Subordinate Adverbial Clauses, which are introduced by adverbs such as *when, before, after, until, once, as soon as,* etc.

**EDIT:** There are many types of Adverbial Clauses, this one is "Adverbial Clause of Time".

Answer (score 2):

Subordinating conjunctions, such as "when", and "though" can take either:

- a full finite clause (with a subject and finite verb, as "when he works alone"), or
- an adjectival phrase, where the adjective may be a participle, as "when working alone" or "when seen by somebody else", but can also be an ordinary adjective, as "when ready".

They cannot take a non-finite clause with an infinitive verb, as "when work alone".

Answer (score 1):

Several terms exist to describe a clause like *when working alone*. The most satisfying one I know is **[elliptical clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29)**: a clause in which words are omitted that the reader can easily infer. In this case, a form of the verb *to be* has been omitted, as well as a pronoun: *when [he is] working alone*. The same construction is possible with other conjunctions:

> Her father, *though [he was] seriously
>   **hurt** by his fall,* kept his face calm
>   and his voice low.

This construction also exists with adjectives instead of participles:

> The lid of the container, *though [it was] **hotter** than before,*
>   was not yet melting.

---

I think the traditional term *elliptical clause* is the most elegant way to explain how some subordinate conjunctions can seemingly do without finite verbs; the simplest model to describe a clause is that it requires a finite verb, be it explicit or implicit. I am not a big fan of grammar books that use the term *clause* so loosely as to include anything that can have arguments/complements/modifiers; there are many words that can have arguments, such as participles:

> The Emperor feared that Bavaria, ***teeming***,
>   as always, with dissenting nobles and
>   fanatical priests, might vote for the
>   Archbishop of Cologne next time.

Some would call *teeming, as always, with dissenting nobles and fanatical priests* a clause. But what will they say if I substitute *rife*?

> The Emperor feared that Bavaria, ***rife***,
>   as always, with dissenting nobles and
>   fanatical priests, might vote for the
>   Archbishop of Cologne next time.

Would they call this a clause as well? They should, because both sentences are nearly they same. But calling an adjective with a few arguments a clause seems like a very bad idea. We could call anything that can have arguments a clause, then; and the adjective should still be called a "clause" even when it doesn't have any of those: for why should the presence of an argument change the lexical category of a word, if the word itself still functions in precisely the same way?

Let's just stick with the simplest model possible and call the *teeming* example a *participial phrase*; we could add that it is used *attributively*, or perhaps predicatively (though I am not a fan of this vague term). A participle is not a clause unless it is clear that a finite verb has been omitted. Certainly, in the end it doesn't matter which terms and models we choose, as linguistic descriptions are not *Dinge an sich*; but this is the simplest choice, if we don't want to mess up many other terms too.

Comment: How does the elliptical clause analysis handle examples like *She hated [his leaving her]* or *I remember [her telling me to stay safe]*?

Comment: @Cerberus What do you mean by “used attributively”? It seems like you must not mean [this sense of “attributively”](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1223704).

Comment: I have a lot of questions because I haven't really been exposed to this viewpoint before. Do you consider the imperative *Be quiet* a clause? Is *be* finite there?

Comment: Consider the parallels here: *Sometimes I [bake cookies / give him a hard time / try to fix it]. There I was, [baking cookies / giving him a hard time / trying to fix it].* Does the elliptical clause analysis cover these?

Comment: The difference in meaning between *It fell on my toe, breaking* and *It fell, breaking my toe* is easily explained if you know the difference between the declarative clauses *It broke* and *It broke my toe*. So it seems sensible to say that *breaking* is a verb in both.

Comment: @Jason: I like your scepticism. *She hated [his leaving her]*: *leaving* is traditionally considered a gerund, a noun-verb (not a participle); this is a special class. Cf. *doing this is wrong* v. *it is wrong to do this*: the gerund generally has the same function as the infinitive, as it describes an action, but it can be used like a noun, syntactically.

Comment: By *attributively* I meant *that modifies a noun*: but, as you could see, I did not use the term wholeheartedly. I find attributive/predicative a problematic distinction. Consider *the house on the prairie is beautiful*: the prepositional phrase *on the prairie* modifies a noun (*house*) and hence should be attributive. Or shouldn't it? If not, what to call it, then? I have no problems dropping this term; but I'd like a term that means *that modifies a noun*, as opposed to *that modifies the whole sentence*. Perhaps *adjectival* would be better? But I feel that that isn't generally so used.

Comment: @JasonOrendorf: *Be quiet* is a clause, because *be* is not an infinitive, but an imperative, which is its own mood (as opposed to indicative and subjunctive) and a finite verb. At least this is the traditional model, with which I have no problems.

Comment: @JasonOrendorf: *There I was, [baking cookies]*: this is the same as my *teeming* example: the participial phrase is used to modify *I* (whether you call it adjectival, attributive, or predicative). It is not a clause, and it is fine without assuming that it was an elliptical clause. // As a gerund is a noun-verb, so a participle is often an adjective-verb: it is both adjective and verb here (but not finite verb). It is a verb inasmuch that it can have typically verbal arguments, like an object, and an adjective in that it modifies a (pro)noun (I). (An infinitive is often both verb and noun.)

Comment: @JasonOrendorf: *It fell on my toe, breaking* and *It fell, breaking my toe*: the participle is a verb all right, with verbal arguments—just not a finite verb. And I call a clause only what has a finite verb. If you call *breaking my toe* a clause, so you must call *going to Spain* a clause, in *passengers going to Spain should get off in Toulouse*. Then what about *passengers on their way to Spain*: is *on their way to Spain* a clause? I think not. (The only thing special about *breaking my toe* is that only verbs can have objects: it is not the fact that they can have arguments at all.)

Comment: @Cerberus Thanks for your generous replies. Regarding attributive/predicative, I think the simplest thing must be to say that it's clearly not a dichotomy—just a contrast. They are the two main ways to use adjectives. But there are others, as in *I want something blue*, and of course there are plenty of other ways to modify a noun. Preposition phrases and relative clauses modify nouns postpositively all the time. The *teeming* example is, I think, what *CGEL* calls a supplement. Apposition is another.

Comment: In reply your last comment, I think traditional grammar often classifies things by function (in *noun clause*, *noun* refers to how the clause is used, not anything in particular about its internal structure) whereas modern grammar almost always classifies things by form (internal structure, including the form and function of each internal part). This has the advantage of more often classifying identical phrases identically...

Comment: Anyway, I think that’s why in *passengers [going to Spain / on their way to Spain / that are going to Spain / ready to go to Spain]* modern grammar classifies each postmodifier differently (gerund-participial clause, PP, relative clause, AdjP with infinitival clause complement). It also explains why modern grammar calls so many of them clauses. It’s simply a matter of their internal structure. Where *go* is used as a verb and supports the whole range of dependents that *go* could take in the predicate of a declarative clause, *CGEL* would say there is a clause.